# Kendo Textbox enable / Disable according to multiple statuses

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo ui textbox and i need to enable / disable that control accoding to status.It works for 1 status but when i put another status with that it's not working

### **Control**

### Below one is working

```
  @Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => model.NewsName).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" }).Enable(Model.NewsStatusId != 340)
```

When i put two status it's not working

```
@Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => model.NewsName).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" }).Enable(Model.NewsStatusId != 340 || Model.NewsStatusId != 345)
```

How can i use it for two statuses ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to do

```
(Model.NewsStatusId != 340 && Model.NewsStatusId != 345)
```

instead of

```
(Model.NewsStatusId != 340 || Model.NewsStatusId != 345)
```

As written, your code will always evaluate to true.